# Create a custom resource model that fetches data from 3rd-party API (non-db)

Tags: model, custom, resource-model, data, third-party-module

I'd like to create a custom model that connects to an API instead of the Magento database. It would also be nice to be able to use (or extend) Magento's collection classes. We created a custom module not so long ago that stores information in the database but we're moving this sub-system outside of Magento and making it accessible through an API to Magento and other apps.

If I can somehow extend Magento's core abstract classes (or maybe inplement some interfaces) I think I can manage to swap my model classes without changing most of the other code that already exists in controllers, blocks, views, etc. Right now, I've created a class that connects to the API and makes the returned data accessible in an object, and a (sort of) collection class that is iterable, but I have to go through the existing code to change how everything works because these are not children of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

**Has anyone done this?**

**Is this viable?** I wonder if implementing these clases would take too much work, maybe nearly as much as just rewriting them from scratch.

Comment: I'm new to this, could you share the full example?

Comment: @Manuel sorry man, this was more than 5 years ago, in an older version of Magento. I don't really remember any of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is Yes!  It is possible.  The resource models inside Magento are responsible for the CRUD operations of a module.  So, based upon that, all you have to do is leverage the `save()`, `delete()`, and `load()` methods inside of your resource model and collection, following the same definition of each method from its parent.

You can still use `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`.

Make sure you are *not* calling parent methods in overridden method definitions.  You are replacing functionality, not appending it.

Here is an oversimplified example:

**Model**

You won't really have to do anything different here.  The CRUD operations in the model will reach out to the resource model.

```
class Coolryan_Module_Model_Example extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('coolryan_module/example'); // define your resource model
    }
}
```

**Resource Model**

The resource model is where you will implement most of your functionality.

```
class Coolryan_Module_Model_Resource_Example extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        // you may want to connect to your api here...
    }

    public function save(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object) {
        // save operations here
        // make sure to update your model with the data!
    }

    public function load(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value, $field = null) {
        // loading operations here
        // make sure to update your model with the data!
    }

    public function delete(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object) {
        // delete operations here
    }
}
```

**Resource Collection**

Collections are pretty straightforward.  The only method you will need to override by default is the `load()` method.  The save operation is not necessary, due to the fact that saving iterates over each item in the collection and calls the `save()` method against each of them.

```
class Coolryan_Module_Model_Resource_Example_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {

    public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false) {
        // load collections of data here...
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!  Happy coding!

Comment: Man, this sounds way easier. I ended up doing something different which is basically rewriting them from scratch but I've only implemented fetching.  Now I'll have to drop all that work because this makes a lot more sense xD Oh well. Occupational hazards.